# VBA SumIfs with OR criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following formula, which works when I enter it into an Excel cell:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Hours!$S:$S, Hours!$N:$N, 'HR Scorecard'!$D$2, Hours!$H:$H, {-2,-3}))
```

I am now trying to convert this to a VBA function.  The issue I am having is that it says { is an invalid character.

```
sumact = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(wsHours.Columns(S), wsHours.Columns(N), A2, wsHours.Columns(H), {-2,-3}))
```

So my first question is, what do I replace {-2, -3} with to get this to work?
Second, do I need Application.WorkSheetFunction before both Sum and SumIfs?

Edit:  I did get this to work by passing it to the cells as a string, but I need to pass the value, not the formula, to the cells.

Comment: Other than a string, maybe try converting it to an array: Array(-2, -3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run "Regular" excel formulas in VBA, enclose them with brackets.

```
sumact= [SUM(SUMIFS(Hours!$S:$S, Hours!$N:$N, 'HR Scorecard'!$D$2, Hours!$H:$H, {-2,-3}))]
```

Should work.

Comment: This is really close.  One thing I still need. I replaced 'HR Scorecard'!$D$2 with 'A2'. I have a select-case statement that is changing the current sheet to cycle between several sheets.  How do I access cell A2 of the currently selected sheet?

Comment: Clarification:  In cell A2 of each sheet, I have a 2-digit identifier.  I need to find all the matches in Hours!$N for this identifier.  If I replace 'HR Scorecard'!$D$2 with one of the codes (i.e. "MV"), it works fine.  But when I create a string variable called 'pc' and use that variable to replace 'HR Scorecard'!$D$2, it does not find any matches.

Comment: I think it may be easier to use the conditionals and functions in VBA instead of trying to do Excel formulas and passing variables into them.

Comment: To get the value of A2 in the Active Sheet: variable= activesheet.range("A2").value

Comment: I can get the value without issue; but when it's inside the [sum(sumif... etc, it's treated like a string rather than a variable, so I think it's evaluating as 'pc' rather than 'MV'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate the example since I am missing some information about the data and the rest of the code. However, try this:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    sumact = .Sum(.SumIfs(wsHours.Columns(S), wsHours.Columns(N), A2, wsHours.Columns(H), Array(-2,-3)))
End With
```

The corrections are:

1. Writing the last input as an array (as suggested in the comment to your question);
2. Using the "With" block to access the methods of the Application.WorksheetFunctions.

Comment: This gives me an Application-defined or object-defined error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that array formulas don't behave well when integrated in VBA. I can't really explain it since I'm lacking in knowledge of how they even work as formulas, but implementing them in VBA is almost an exercise in futility unless you know what you're doing.

That said, if performance isn't so much of an issue, just use `Evaluate`. For example, the following subroutine performs as expected:

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox Evaluate("=SUM(2,3)") 'Shows a message box: 5
End Sub
```

Assuming the following table in `Sheet5`:

```
Foo     10
Bar     15
Grok    30
Spam    20
Foo     50
Bar     60
Grok    20
Spam    90
```

The following subroutine performs as expected as well:

```
Sub Test2()
    MsgBox Evaluate("=SUMIF(Sheet5!$A:$A,""Foo"",Sheet5!$B:$B)") '60
End Sub
```

You can even store it in a variable if so needed.

```
Sub Test3()
    ans = Evaluate("=SUMIF(Sheet5!$A:$A,""Grok"",Sheet5!$B:$B)") '50
    MsgBox ans
End Sub
```

Admittedly, since it's executed from VBA, the speed takes a little hit. However, the ease of application far outweighs the overhead of coding a pure VBA variant.